# How to display label in the same line as input when text in label is bigger than width of this label?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to display text in width for example : 33.33% and input: 66.34%. When text in label is longer than width break it to several lanes and display first word (letters) on same row as input. You can try it on mobile phone on my site. Now when text is bigger then width of label it display above input in same line. Website: [site](http://testing3.ats-global.com//cz/cs/7_contacts.html). Thank you.
PS: Try on 480px.

CSS:

```
#form input.ui-input-text, textarea.ui-input-text {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 66.64% !important;
}
#form [data-role='fieldcontain'] > label{
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 33.33% !important;
}
textarea { vertical-align: middle; }​
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="f_FName">Name: *</label>
  <input id="f_FName" type="text" value=""  name="f_FName">
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="f_CAdd">Adresa</label>
  <textarea id="f_CAdd" class="ui-input-text ui-body-d ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" cols="30" rows="2" name="f_CAdd" type="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
#form input.ui-input-text, textarea.ui-input-text {
    width: 66.64%;
}
#form [data-role='fieldcontain'] > label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;/* keep text on one line */
}
textarea { vertical-align: middle; }​
```